# SCSM Web Request Portal - My Request Filter

Tags: request, portal, sccm

Just wondering if it is possible to modify the filter that gets applied for the My Requests tab in the web request portal. Currently its only showing service requests and incidents created by me, but I want to change it so that it also shows any change requests that have also been created by me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint portal or new HTML 5 portal?

Comment: I believe it is an HTML5 portal.

Answer (score 0):

In simple answer - no.

I’d recommend that if such thing is needed you write a simple MVC site that does that for you (hosted beside the self service portal)

Any changes made to the portal will mean that when you come to patching it with updates it will break.